# Java Generics: Implement multiple sub-interfaces of an generic interface

Tags: java, generics

I've following codes.

```
interface Observer<T> {
    void update();
}
```

```
interface FirstClassObserver extends Observer<FirstClass>{ }
```

```
interface SecondClassObserver extends Observer<SecondSecond> { }
```

Now, I'm required to do as follows.

```
class MainClass implements FirstClassObserver, SecondClassObserver {
}
```

But Eclipse give following problem with the code.

`The interface Observer cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments: FirstClassObserver<FirstClass> and SecondClassObserver<SecondClass>`

Is there a way that I can write my MainClass like

```
class MainClass implements FirstClassObserver, SecondClassObserver {
   @Override
   void FirstClassObserver::update() { /* ... / }
   @Override
   void SecondClassObserver::update() { / ... */ }
}
```

Comment: No. Due to the way generics are implemented in Java, you cannot do that.

Comment: Because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), you aren't going to be able to do this. Basically, all generic type parameters end up as `Object` in the compiled byte code.

Comment: Which one is supposed to be used if someone calls MainClass.update()??? The two methods have the exact same signature!

Comment: Thanks. I'll try some other way. :/

Comment: How do I tag this question as "Closed" ?

Comment: @TheKojuEffect You can post your own answer and then accept it. You should also be able to simply delete the question, if you think that's appropriate.

Comment: @TedHopp Other people may get this type of issue, so I'm not gonna delete question but will write an answer.

Comment: @assylias While developing in C++, we do manage to handle this type of situation. Also since Java being single inheritance with class but multiple inheritance with inheritance, thought it will be fine.

Comment: What you want to do doesn't make sense (in my opinion).  Once you have to make up new syntax to support something, it's a good sign it's not going to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing multiple generic interfaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290558/implementing-multiple-generic-interfaces). See also: [How to make a Java class that implements one interface with two generic types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297972/how-to-make-a-java-class-that-implements-one-interface-with-two-generic-types)

Answer (score 3):

According to `@Ted`'s comment.
Because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), you aren't going to be able to do this.
Basically, all generic type parameters end up as Object in the compiled byte code.

Also according to `@assylias`'s comment, there can be ambiguous situation as whose instance of `update()` method to call `MainClass.update()` is invoked.