# Java class with a generic type parameter that instantiates a different generic interface

Tags: java, generics

I've found a [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290558/implementing-multiple-generic-interfaces?lq=1) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297972/how-to-make-a-java-class-that-implements-one-interface-with-two-generic-types) about the java limitation of not being able to implement the same interface twice with different type paramters.  (e.g., you can't be `Iterable<String>` and `Iterable<Integer>`), but I haven't found any discussion of the following case.

I can say

```
    public class A implements Iterable<Integer> {    
        public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }
```

and I can say

```
    public class A<T> {
        T getFoo() { 
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        void setFoo(T foo) { 
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }
```

But it's not clear to me why the following isn't allowed.  **[See correction below.]**  It seems like the first case already "drops" the type Integer from the generic specification of A (I didn't have to say `A<Integer>` in case #1.)  So why can't we give A a new type T like this?

```
    public class A<T> implements Iterable<Integer> {
        T getFoo() { 
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        void setFoo(T foo) { 
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

    }
```

---

By the way, if I change the first case to

```
    public class A<Integer> implements Iterable<Integer> {
```

I get a "hiding" warning, that the `Integer` (on the left I presume) is hiding the other type `Integer`.

Actually, that's not quite right!  Changing it to

```
    public class A<String> implements Iterable<Integer> {
```

says that `String` is hiding `String`, not hiding `Integer`.  I'm not even sure what that means. `A<String>` is allowed with `Iterable<Integer>` while `A<T>` is not — that's the crux of my question.

---

**Edit:**

I found the problem with my example.  For the example, I changed to `Iterable<Integer>` from our own interface `LinkableVertex<OurLinkClass>`, thinking it didn't make a difference. `OurLinkClass` already implemented `LinkableEdge<A>`.  The actual error in Eclipse is:

```
Bound mismatch: The type OurLinkClass is not a valid substitute for the
bounded parameter <E extends LinkableEdge<? extends LinkableVertex<E>>> of 
the type LinkableVertex<E>
```

(In case it's relevant, this is a recursive pair of interfaces: `LinkableVertex<E extends LinkableEdge<? extends LinkableVertex<E>>>` and `LinkableEdge<V extends LinkableVertex<? extends LinkableEdge<V>>>`)

That said, while I haven't got it all cleared up, and I'm not sure why the extra type is required instead of just a raw type warning, the problem may be as simple as changing `OurLinkClass` to implement `LinkableVertex<A<?>>`

Sorry about that!

Comment: public class A<T> implements Iterable<Integer> - it works fine for me

Comment: Your type looks like it should work just fine.  What goes wrong?

Comment: It works: https://ideone.com/83JlCy

Comment: Hang on, I agree, this is working for me now.  I'll try to figure out what was wrong when I was looking at it in my IDE before.

Comment: Added an edit to clear up what had gone wrong on the way to my code example.

Answer (score 2):

The hiding means that the name used for your generic may be hiding a class: `java.lang.String`.

There's a huge difference between using generics for class definition and using it for variable (local, parameter, field, etc) definition.

It's not the same to define this:

```
public class A<String> {
             //^----^----- name of your generic used in the class
    public String getFoo() {
    }
}
```

Than declaring this:

```
A<String> a; //here A will work with generics but using java.lang.String class
```

Also, your class can implement an interface that use generics but that doesn't mean your class must use generics as well. Here's an example:

```
class MyClass<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    //this means MyClass will use a generic of name T and implements Iterable
    //to support the same generic T used in the class
}

class AnotherClass implements Iterable<String> {
    //this means that AnotherClass doesn't support generics
    //and implements Iterable for java.lang.String only.
}
```

Comment: Ah, so String in that case is acting as a generic type name that could refer to another type like Integer?  Talk about obfuscation!

Comment: whoa yeah, it's just allowing String as a variable typename.  This is perfectly okay aside from the hiding!  `public class A<String extends HashMap> implements Iterable<Integer> {`

Comment: That's correct. Be careful with the name of your generic :)

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg I don't know why they allowed this. It's a common cause of confusion. IMHO type parameters should be capped at 3 characters max.