# how does implement multiple types asynctaskloader

Tags: android, asynctaskloader

I want to use two type `asynctaskloader` in one `FragmentActivity`.

```
class MyLoader1 extends AsyncTaskLoader<String>{}
class MyLoader2 extends AsyncTaskLoader<Integer>{}
```

I write as follows. but it compile error.

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity 
               implements LoaderCallbacks<String>, LoaderCallbacks<Integer>{}
```

Please show me answer with easy sample code.

---

Thanks so much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a Java class that implements one interface with two generic types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297972/how-to-make-a-java-class-that-implements-one-interface-with-two-generic-types)

Answer (score 1):

As hjpotter92 mentions, this is how Java handles generics. In this case, I would just suggest using anonymous classes as indicated in hjpotter92's link.

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {
     private LoaderCallbacks<String> mLoaderCallbackString = new LoaderCallbacks<String>() {
           ...
     };

     private LoaderCallbacks<Integer> mLoaderCallbackInteger = new LoaderCallbacks<Integer>() {
           ...
     };
}
```

Then for each loader, you just pass the correct LoaderCallbacks object