# How to implement the same interface multiple times, but with different generics?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have the following interface, which I want to implement multiple times in my classes:

```
public interface EventListener<T extends Event>
{
    public void onEvent(T event);
}
```

Now, I want to be able to implement this interface in the following way:

```
class Foo implements EventListener<LoginEvent>, EventListener<LogoutEvent>
{

    @Override
    public void onEvent(LoginEvent event)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(LogoutEvent event)
    {

    }
}
```

However, this gives me the error: `Duplicate class com.foo.EventListener` on the line:

```
class Foo implements EventListener<LoginEvent>, EventListener<LogoutEvent>
```

Is it possible to implement the interface twice with different generics? If not, what's the next closest thing I can do to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Derive a sub-interface of `EventListener<OneOfThoseEventTypes>`, and have this class implement that? (I don't know if it would work, I'm just tossing it out as a possible workaround.)

Comment: @keshlam i still wouldn't be able to have two separate methods for handling login and logout events in that case.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297972/how-to-make-a-java-class-that-implements-one-interface-with-two-generic-types

Comment: JFYI You can achieve this in C# by the explicit interface implementation.

Comment: check this functional style with compile time type checking example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60466413/4121845

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use inner or anonymous classes.  For instance:

```
class Foo {
   public EventListener<X> asXListener() {
      return new EventListener<X>() {
          // code here can refer to Foo
      };
   }


  public EventListener<Y> asYListener() {
      return new EventListener<Y>() {
          // code here can refer to Foo
      };
   }
}
```

Comment: Is this a LIMITATION of java?
Or is it done so intentionally?

Comment: @Suresh Kumar  It is a limitation of Java due to type erasure of generics.  Note that in Java 8 the syntax for the anonymous classes will be shorter and arguably simpler.

Answer (score 30):

> Is it possible to implement the interface twice with different generics

Unfortunately no. The reason you can't implement the same interface twice is because of type erasure. The compiler will handle type parameters, and a runtime `EventListener<X>` is just a `EventListener`

---

> If not, what's the next closest thing I can do to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Type erasure can work in our favor. Once you know that `EventListener<X>` and `EventListener<Y>` are just raw `EventListener` at run-time, it is easier than you think to write an `EventListener` that can deal with different kinds of `Events`. Bellow is a solution that passes the `IS-A` test for `EventListener` and correctly handles both `Login` and `Logout` events by means of simple delegation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class Foo implements EventListener {

    // Map delegation, but could be anything really
    private final Map<Class<? extends Event>, EventListener> listeners;

    // Concrete Listener for Login - could be anonymous
    private class LoginListener implements EventListener<LoginEvent> {
        public void onEvent(LoginEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Login");
        }
    }

    // Concrete Listener for Logout - could be anonymous        
    private class LogoutListener implements EventListener<LogoutEvent> {
        public void onEvent(LogoutEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Logout");
        }
    }

    public Foo() {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Map<Class<? extends Event>, EventListener> temp  = new HashMap<>();
        // LoginEvents will be routed to LoginListener
        temp.put(LoginEvent.class, new LoginListener());
        // LogoutEvents will be routed to LoginListener
        temp.put(LogoutEvent.class, new LogoutListener());
        listeners = Collections.unmodifiableMap(temp);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        // Maps make it easy to delegate, but again, this could be anything
        if (listeners.containsKey(event.getClass())) {
            listeners.get(event.getClass()).onEvent(event);
        } else {
            /* Screams if a unsupported event gets passed
             * Comment this line if you want to ignore
             * unsupported events
             */
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Event not supported");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        System.out.println(foo instanceof EventListener); // true
        foo.onEvent(new LoginEvent()); // Login
        foo.onEvent(new LogoutEvent()); // Logout
    }
}
```

The suppress warnings are there because we are "abusing" type erasure and delegating to two different event listeners based on the event concrete type. I have chosen to do it using a `HashMap` and the run-time Event `class`, but there are a lot of other possible implementations. You could use anonymous inner classes like @user949300 suggested, you could include a `getEventType` discriminator on the Event class to know what do to with each event and so on.

By using this code for all effects you are creating a single `EventListener` able to handle two kinds of events. The workaround is 100% self-contained (no need to expose the internal `EventListeners`).

Finally, there is one last issue that may bother you. At compile time `Foo` type is actually `EventListener`. Now, API methods out of your control may be expecting parametrized `EventListener`s:

```
public void addLoginListener(EventListener<LoginEvent> event) { // ...
// OR
public void addLogoutListener(EventListener<LogoutEvent> event) { // ...
```

Again, at run-time both of those methods deal with raw `EventListener`s. So by having `Foo` implement a raw interface the compiler will be happy to let you get away with just a type safety warning (which you can disregard with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`):

```
eventSource.addLoginListener(foo); // works
```

While all of this may seem daunting, just repeat to yourself "The compiler is trying to trick me (or save me); there is no <del>spoon</del> `<T>`. Once you scratch your head for a couple of months trying to make legacy code written before Java 1.5 work with modern code full of type parameters, type erasure becomes second nature to you.

Comment: +1 for type erasure thing

Comment: is this going to be possible in java 8? :(

Comment: Can you cross the same interface twice?  :-). Obscure Heraclius quote.

Comment: @user949300, the compiler is smart, it will fail to compile saying that `The interface xxx cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments`. But take a look at my code to see how you can make it work with raw types.

Comment: I like the Map trick.  Have used it myself.

Comment: @Click Upvote: No, type erasure is still the mechanism for generics on Java 8. The only way to make what you want possible is by rewriting the entire Java generic system and breaking compatibility with older versions of Java (like Microsoft did when it introduced generics on .NET 2.0). I doubt that Java will make that move.

Comment: Works, but it seems like a hack.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.
But for that you could create two different `classes` that implement `EventListener` interface with two different arguments.

```
public class Login implements EventListener<LoginEvent> {

    public void onEvent(LoginEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}

public class Logout implements EventListener<LogoutEvent> {

    public void onEvent(LogoutEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }   
}
```