# Java multiple inheritance using two interface having same method but different parameters

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

When I tried to do Controller so, I`ve got a message: Listener cannot be inherited with different arguments AlfaMsg and GammaMsg. I read some patterns, but it does not help me. How I can realize this idea?

```
public abstract class Msg {

}   

public class AlfaMsg extends Msg{


}

public class GammaMsg extends Msg{


}

public interface Listener<T extends Msg> {
   void update(String message, T msg);    
}

public interface ListenerAlfa  extends Listener<AlfaMsg> {
   @Override    
   void update(String message, AlfaMsg deviceMessage);    
}

public interface ListenerGamma  extends Listener<GammaMsg> {
   @Override    
   void update(String message, GammaMsg deviceMessage);    
}

public class Controller implements ListenerAlfa, ListenerGamma{

    @Override
    void update(String message, AlfaMsg deviceMessage){

    }

    @Override
    void update(String message, GammaMsg deviceMessage){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this using generics, because of type erasure - so that `Controller` would be implementing the same `Listener` interface twice.

You may want to review a [previous answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297972/how-to-make-a-java-class-that-implements-one-interface-with-two-generic-types/60466413#60466413), it has some workaround using encapsulation, but I am not sure this is what you'd like to implement.